# Stripe manual billing on subscriptions

Tags: stripe-payments

Does anyone know how to make a subscription in stripe bill manually. Some customers don't want our system automatically billing their credit cards and they don't want to have to just remove their credit cards every time. I also don't want to convert to just using single invoices for these customers. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is not a feature that Stripe support at the moment. You would need to use we

Comment: What is "we" stand for?

Comment: sorry looks like I cut out my own sentence. I meant "you would need to use webhook to catch this and delete the card automatically each time"

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is to set `collection_method` to `send_invoice` on the subscription. It's documented [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-collection_method).

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow!! It would be great if you could [read these guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before answering any question. Thanks.